# Difference in data between Google Analytics 4 API and UI

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm automating the data collection from a Google Analytics 4 property.
However, whenever i'm trying to match the API data with the property data I get slight differences.

For example, when I get these fields (see image below) for february and march. The total sessions from the API data is: 188.213, while the Google Analytics UI shows 189.042.

When I make the API query, really simple, by just pulling the sessions between february and march then I get the 189.042 totally perfect. Why do I get a difference when I add some dimensions?

I hope somebody can explain. Business users need to trust the data, so it must match in my opinion. Thanks for answering in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where there were differences between the API and the GA4 Interface results, in particular when I added multiple dimensions. I finally found out that it was caused by the [GA4 data threshold](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630), as Sharon also mentioned in their comment to MeasureHub.org's answer in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76006877/data-retrieved-by-google-analytics-4-data-api-doesnt-match-that-from-web-interf/78008542#78008542).

Using less dimensions in my queries mostly produced the same results in via the API and the GA4 Interface, but for some reporting we needed more information.

In the end, for the company it was more important to have all available data in our reporting, hence I deactivated Google Signals as suggested in the link above. Once I did it, the UI and API results were exactly the same.

If Google Signals is required, it is not possible to guarantee an exact match between the two sets of results. Careful selection of dimensions is required, together with checks between the API and the Interface, but this mostly defeats the purpose of getting the data programatically.